# Angular 2: ActivatedRouter wont take 3 arguments

Tags: angular

ActivatedRouter wont take 3 arguments. it gives error as below. please help.

error:

```
[ts] Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.
```

code:

```
this._router.navigate(['child',id], {queryParams: { page: id }}, { fragment: 'top' });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only pass 2 arguments to `this.router.navigate()` additional options can pass like this

```
let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
  queryParams: { page: id },
  fragment: 'top'
};

this.router.navigate(['child',id], navigationExtras);
```

you can check this [doc](https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments) for more.